# G++ log10(float) log10(double)

Tags: c++, g++

I have enabled `-Wdouble-promotion` and the code below compiles without warning. Before this change I was attempting to simply use `log10()` assuming that the compiler would call `log10(float)`. Under those conditions it complained that `10.0f` was promoted to double presumably because `log10(double)` was being called. Any thoughts? I'd prefer not to use the builtin.

I'm using C++14 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ arm-xilinx-eabi-g++ --version
arm-xilinx-eabi-g++ (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2014.11-31) 4.9.1

#include <math.h>

F32 Power::dbm(F32 watts)
{
    return 10.0f * __builtin_log10f(watts * 1000.0f);
}

Building file: ../Source/Power.cpp
Invoking: ARM g++ compiler
arm-xilinx-eabi-g++ -Wall -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0 -MT"Source/Power.o"  -std=c++14 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -Wdouble-promotion -MMD -MP -MF"Source/Power.d" -MT"Source/Power.d" -o "Source/Power.o" "../Source/Power.cpp"
Finished building: ../Source/Power.cpp
```

Comment: What other compiler settings are you using? Which header did you include?

Comment: If `F32` is a typedef for `float`, then `decltype(watts*1000.0f) === float`, `decltype(std::log10(watts*1000.0f)) === float` and `decltype(10.0f * std::log10(watts * 1000.0f)) === float`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I added the information you requested. Thanks.

Comment: @Pixelchemist That's what I expected but it told me it was going to promote 10.0f to a double to match the return value of log10().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including a C header, `math.h`, which doesn't provide an overload for `log10` taking `float`. If you want overloaded version of `log10` include `cmath` and use [`std::log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10):

```
std::log10(watts * 1000.0f)
```

or, as suggested by Ongun, use [`log10f`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log10):

```
log10f(watts * 1000.0f)
```

Comment: Thank you. At some point I tried including <cmath> and calling std::log10() but apparently not at the same time. This compiles without the warning.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong function for floats. Use `log10f()`.

Definitions are like below:

```
double log10(double x);
float log10f(float x);
long double log10l(long double x);
```

Source:
`man 3 log10`

Comment: This is true for C but C++ overloads log10 based on the parameter type. Though using the C version would be better than what I have.

Comment: @Kenny g++ supports C99 extensions on top of C++, some compilers (notably Microsoft) do not. You're better off using the standard C++ methods that work everywhere.